# Attempting to determine if large Twitter API query using 'rtweet' is still actually downloading

Tags: r, rtweet, sttwitterapi

I am attempting to download every instance of a hashtag (#Venture) using the R package `` rtweet` and am seeing a messaging indicating that the data is downloading but stopping at 16% with the progress bar unfinished. I understand the API limits a query to 18k tweets per 15 minute interval, but what is confusing me is that my R prompt ``R>``` has returned as though the query has finished or aborted. Am I just being impatient or am I missing something?

I've tried to play around with the argument `retryonratelimit = TRUE`; I've tried executing the query again. I've looked through a few tutorials and looked up the package documentation. I'm just confused why the Downloading progress bar quit only after 16% never to re-initiate or at least abort and throw an error message.

```
R> ## search for 250,000 tweets containing the word data
R> venture1 <- search_tweets(
+   "#venture", n = 200000, include_rts = FALSE, retryonratelimit = TRUE
+ )
Downloading [=====>-----------------------------------]  16%
R>
```

Comment: Typically if you can see the next `>` on an interactive window, that suggests execution is finished. Sometimes there are visual bugs though so try `print('asdf')`. If it prints that means it wasn't doing anything else

Comment: Hmm. I did just download the most recent development version from Github. There's a CRAN version. I'm thinking I maybe should remove the package and reinstall the older version and see what happens. I'm just so disgusted to see the downloading progress bar incomplete with, no error message, and the ```>```.

Comment: Okay, uninstalled the developmental Github version; installed CRAN version. Run the code again and this is what I received: 

```R> venture1 <- search_tweets(
+   "#venture", n = 200000, include_rts = FALSE, retryonratelimit = TRUE
+ )
Searching for tweets...
This may take a few seconds...
Finished collecting tweets!
Searching for tweets...
This may take a few seconds...
Finished collecting tweets!
Searching for tweets...
This may take a few seconds...
Finished collecting tweets!
R> 
R> nrow(venture1)
[1] 460
R> 
``` 
Yet I know there are more than 460 hashtags #Venture...